# Basic commutation confusion for operators $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

I'm going through my quantum mechanics course and have become a little stuck on something very basic, how can we prove that the operator $\hat{X}$ commutes with $\hat{Y}$?

I can simply get to the step where $$[\hat{X},\hat{Y}] = \hat{X}\hat{Y} - \hat{Y}\hat{X}$$

But can't see how I can end up with $[\hat{X},\hat{Y}] = 0$ which is what is necessary for them to commute?

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are *postulated* to commute. You cannot prove it, because it is one of the axioms of the theory. The reason for this axiom is that the classical coordinates $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ have vanishing Poisson bracket:
$$\{x,y\}=0$$
(which I invite you to prove) and therefore the quantisation rule is to take $[X,Y]=0$. Again, this can be motivated but not proven. It is a postulate of QM.